# On The Subject of Binary Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Binary Puzzle

0000010001111001000010110110010010010011111000011111010011000001010111000101000000010100011000011101011110111011110111010110101100000000000000000001001000111000011101010000000111001101110000010111100011100100010000001000000000100101011101010000100000011000000000000000000000000000100001111000000000000000000010110111100011101110110100101000011001000010000000010101010001100100000010000100111011100010111101011000000000000000001000000000101000010000000011000001111100100111101011001000000001001011001000001111100100010010110000000

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Logged

First we must

> arrange the numbers into a $23\times 23$ grid. I have colored the numbers here black=1, white=0[image]
> The first square tells us to look at the middle columns which clearly spell "DELETE".
>
> Deleting those columns and arranging the remaining numbers into a $17\times 23$ grid, we get [image]
> spelling "THIS TOO" in the middle cells as hinted by the second square.
>
> Deleting those cells and arranging the rest into a $13\times 17$ grid, we get
>  [image]
> The first and last three columns spell "Add 7 bits"
>
> Deleting the first three and last three columns, adding seven bits and arranging the rest into a $18\times 7$ grid, we get the following picture where I have switched white $\rightarrow$ red (except the 7 extra bits are white).
>  [image]

Comment: That answer is correct! (The message that's "a bit harder to read" isn't quite right, though -- it's the first and last three columns.)

Comment: @Deusovi Yes, I can see it now. Edited.